# Cannot comprehend output of sklearn.decomposition.PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, scikit-learn

I am a little confused about PCA algorithm especially the one implemented in sklearn.

when I use pca in sklearn decomposition with a `4000X784` matrix

```
X.shape = (4000,784)

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(X)
pca.explained_variance_.shape
```

I  get

```
(784,)
```

On the other hand when I use another dataset with shape `(50,784)`

```
(50,)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: yes, you are asking the code-related problem without showing as the particular code (data, in this case). Without reproducible example it is hard to say whether you do something wrong. (Yet it seems that you simply put a transposed matrix, print shape of your X variables in both cases and compare them).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

**explained_variance_ratio_** *array, [n_components]* Percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components. k is not set then all components are stored and the sum of explained variances is equal to 1.0

In the first case, your data has 4000 elements with 748 components, so the attribute gives you an array of 748 values. If this is correct, then you need to transpose the second dataset.

Comment: I tried that already. When I transpose the matrix I get the same matrix back.

Answer (score 0):

The maximal number of **components** you get with PCA is equal to the minimum dimension of your X matrix.

The explained_variance_ method shows you how much of the variance of the data is explained by each PCA **component**.

These array shapes are normal because you get 768 components when you have more data than features, but only 50 when you have 50 lines of data.